# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token javaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem, I'm trying to dynamically add some html via javascript, and the html has a js function that's supposed to trigger when it's clicked, but I keep getting this error no matter what I do Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } Has anyone had this problem before?

**`<input type='checkbox' onclick='CheckEngine(" + MakeVal + "," + item.VehicleEngineID + ",this)' checked name='EnginName' value='' />`**

Comment: Would You Like To Make Snippet to Solve?

Comment: Not sure where _that_ code came from, although it's unlikely to cause the error itself (the error _might_ be coming from within CheckEngine). Where do 'MakeVal' and 'item.VehicleEngineID' come from? Is that the *actual HTML text/source*, as sent to the browser, or the source in some server-side language? It seems blatantly incorrect - as in, won't do what is expected at all - if that's verbatim HTML. If that is not the _actual_ HTML, include the _actual_ HTML in the question. If that's part of some other JavaScript, include the "other" JavaScript.